# How to deal with the declaration of variables in a parser.mly?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, parser-generator

I am writing a compiler of mini-pascal in Ocaml. I would like my compiler to accept the following code for instance:

```
program test;
var
   a,b : boolean;
   n : integer;
begin
   ...
end.
```

I have difficulties in dealing with the declaration of variables (the part following `var`). At the moment, the type of variables is defined like this in [sib_syntax.ml](http://paste.ubuntu.com/633728/):

```
type s_var =
    { s_var_name: string;
      s_var_type: s_type; }
```

Here is [sib_parser.mly](http://paste.ubuntu.com/633713/). My question is, where and how I could tell the compiler to build `globals`, the declaration of variables, which is actually a list of `s_var`. I guess I need to refine the part of menhir in the end of `sib_parser.mly`(`terminated_bindings`, `binding`, `separated_nonempty_list`, etc.), but I do not know how...

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, in your binding rules, you have access to `ids` which is a list of variable names, so you could write, for instance:

```
binding:
  | ids = separated_nonempty_list(COMMA, IDENT) COLON INTEGER
      { List.map (fun id -> { s_var_name = id ; s_var_type = St_int}) ids }
  | ids = separated_nonempty_list(COMMA, IDENT) COLON BOOLEAN
      { List.map (fun id -> { s_var_name = id ; s_var_type = St_bool}) ids }
```

This would make the `binding` rule return a `s_var list`.

Comment: thank you very much, that helps. Going forward, I have posted another related [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518436/), if you want to take a look...